# Check the regional administrative code through ip

Tags: java

I am using java language for development, and now there is a scenario where the administrative region code is queried through ip address, without considering the method of calling third-party API. Currently, the place name can be obtained by using the library of ip2Region, but there is no administrative code in it. Is there any ready-made offline file that can support this scenario

The following code can get the city name, such as Wuhan, but now I want to get the city code. For example: 420100, want to see if there is a thread of this toolkit used。

```
public static String getCityInfo(String ip) throws Exception{
        DbSearcher searcher = null;
        Method method = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/ip2region.db");
            inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
            byte[] dbBinStr = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
            DbConfig config = new DbConfig();
            searcher = new DbSearcher(config, dbBinStr);
            method = searcher.getClass().getMethod("memorySearch", String.class);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return ((DataBlock) method.invoke(searcher, ip)).getRegion();
    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to this [`ip2region`](https://github.com/lionsoul2014/ip2region) ?